# How to programmatically cancel the OnTouchListener callback even if the user haven't released the touch from a view in Android?

Tags: android, animation, events, touch, listener

I am working on an Audio Recording App. It works in a way that when the user presses and moves the record button, the button moves along with the finger. I have created a boundary and when the finger crosses that boundary I want the button to perform the `hide()` animation and get back to it orginal position.

The whole process works fine if the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` event is occurred, but the `hide()` operation is not occurring even if the touch crosses the boundary. The button plays a back and forth motion sometimes when it is outside the boundary. The touch event is still being called even if I set the `visibility` of the view to `false`.

I get the output in the logcat as well (`Log.e("MSG","boundary crossed");`).

This is the code:

```
int recordButtonStartX;
microPhoneListner=new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  recordButtonStartX = (int) event.getX();
      this.floatingRecordButton.display(event.getX());
    }
    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

      this.floatingRecordButton.hide(event.getX());

    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    int tempX = (int) event.getX();
     if ((recordButtonStartX - tempX) > 200) {
      Log.e("MSG","boundary crossed");
      this.floatingRecordButton.hide(event.getX());
     }
    else
    {
      this.floatingRecordButton.moveTo(event.getX());
    }
    break;
}
recordMsgButton.setOnTouchListener(microPhoneListner);
```

Comment: You could set a flag when you want to cancel the listener programmatically, and inside the listener check de flag. If flag is true, then stop doing actions even is the listener is being called.

Comment: Since the touch is not cancelled, the button is not going back to the original place. Instead it stays under the finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To release the `onTouchListener` for any `View` set the listener to `null`.

```
recordMsgButton.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

**or**

After your condition satisfied you can set other listener to that `View`.

Make another listener

```
public final OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

When you want to disable the listener then set other listener to that view

```
v.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
```

Comment: But, that button have to be used again. making the `onTouchListener` `null` will permanently remove the touch callback right?

Comment: Still the touch is not being cancelled. The moment I revert back the old listener to the view, it starts to listen to the View immediately. I mean if you don't take your hands off the screen, It never gets cancelled.